# React Native Firebase: Google Sign In works for me but throws Error 10 for the Pre-launch report in Google Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-play, google-signin

When I upload a new Android app to Internal Testing in Google Play Store, automatically the Pre-launch report bot start testing the app.

I even get a recorded video and I can clearly see that the bot clicks on "Sign in with Google", chooses a Google account and then gets "Error 10".

**However** - When I download the SAME version myself, as an Internal Tester, the Google Sign In works flawlessly on my Android device.

I know that error code is related to wrong SHA configurations in Firebase somehow, but I think I've set everything up correctly. I've been following all the official guides, and looked into over 30 articles and StackOverflow threads without success.

How can what I test differ from the Pre-launch report? We're running the same release!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after 2 days of debug hell.

It turns out I had to add both the Google Play Signing SHA1 key AND my local Debug Signing SHA1 key to the Firebase Config of my Android App.

**The Google Play Signing SHA1 can be found in the Google play console:**
[image]

**The local debug signing key SHA1 can be found by running** `./gradlew signingReport` **in the** `android` **folder of your react native app:**

[image]

Comment: where do you find this 'Firebase Config of my Android App'?

Comment: In the Firebase Console, click "Project Settings" and then scroll down to the section "My apps", and select your Android app from the list there.